# ClassFormatError in Java

Tags: java

I'm attempting to help a client who is getting a ClassFormatError. The error message says

```
bytecode array size > 65535 at offset=66370
```

The stack trace indicates that the error occurs when trying to call a static method in a utility class. I cannot reproduce the error on my own system.

I tried Googling the issue (search=classformaterror "bytecode array size", quotes included) and found bug reports for other software, but nothing helpful. I also tried searching here, but couldn't find results involving this particular error message. (Maybe I just failed to find them...)

Any idea what may be causing this issue? I can't post code or the actual stack trace because it's proprietary.

Thanks in advance for any pointers you can give me on where to look.

Comment: I'm still working on this. The client is using a proprietary JRE that I cannot install on my system (installation does a BIOS check to see if you have the right brand of system to use it). It is possible that the JIT compiler is to blame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That suggests the utility class method is basically too big, and needs splitting up. Different compilers will output different amounts of code - and I guess it's also possible that different VMs enforce the constraints more or less strictly.

Additionally, you *may* find that compiling the utility class without debug information will get the method under the limit - but it would be better to just split it up.

Comment: Also, if it's just a big class full of unrelated "utility" methods, it might be time to take a second look at the architecture of the system.

Comment: @Radu The size limit exceeded is the size of a single method, so quite possibly the opposite is true: a long process is crammed into a single method.

Comment: The utility class method is about 30 short lines long, though 17 of those lines are case statements since the entire thing is one big switch statement. (I didn't write the code, I just have to maintain it.) The class does have methods that are much longer (and just as many cases in a switch statement), but this one is pretty short.

Comment: @smacdav: It may well be that loading the class itself is the problem, regardless of which method is called. You could have a look at the bytecode with `javap` to see how big the methods are.

Comment: @Radu I don't disagree; I've been arguing that we need to completely refactor the system since I started working on it, but management and marketing set the priorities and don't see this as a high priority. Maybe this support call will change their minds...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I'm looking at javap output right now; I used the verbose option, so I have a lot of information, but this is the first time I've used the tool. Can you give me a tip on what I'm looking for (or even a place to go that tells me how to interpret this data)?

Comment: @smacdav: Not immediately, I'm afraid - I'm up to my ears in work. You may find a non-verbose option makes it clearer. Or use `javap -c` and have a look at the offsets for the final bytecode in each method.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: That's fair. Thanks for your help. I did run it with the -c option, so I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, @biziclop: Okay, so I took a look at the `javap` output for both the verbose and -c options; the max offset I'm seeing is 8521, which is of course nowhere near 65535. Today is supposed to be a day off for me, so I'm putting this aside until tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @smacdav This is a bit of a long shot, but could it be another class referenced by your utility class?

Comment: @biziclop: Even a long shot is worth looking at for me right now. Unfortunately, I can't find a class the utility class references that could be a problem. There is one interface with over 1500 constants defined in it, but none of the concrete classes referenced are particularly big.

Comment: Apparently I was misreading the size of the bytecode when I saw an offset of 8521. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears that this is simply a "line number" or "bytecode" offset, and one still has to figure out the number of bytes that takes up. Simply multiplying by 8 will give you a rough estimate, but doesn't take into account the few bytecodes that actually take up two bytes.

Comment: @smacdav: Couldn't say for sure, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonSkeet, the client did their own analysis and came up with a number greater than 65,535 for the method length. After much head-banging, I figured out that they got their number by simply counting the number of characters in the method for the text output from javap -verbose. This isn't the right way to check this, is it? It seems to me that this output has MANY characters that are not going to be in the actual bytecode.

Comment: @smacdav: I would personally have expected the "line numbers" to be the byte code offset. Certainly the "number of characters" is entirely incorrect.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have since found a tool (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35915/Java-Class-Viewer) which makes for much easier determination of the size of a method in the class file. With that, I was able to determine that the method is less than 12,000 bytes, which explains why we couldn't reproduce the client's error on our system. I thank you once again for your help; I believe this issue is now closed from our end.

Answer (score 5):

To further elaborate on Jon Skeet's response:

The class file format specifies a 4 byte length field for each method's bytecode array, but in practice certain constructs (the local variable table, the line number table and the exceptions table) limit this to 65535.

The first two of those are optional and are not compiled in if you compile your class without debug info, but the third one is mandatory. Of course if there's no exception handling in the latter part of the method, the compiler may not notice it. Or even worse, it could overflow and compile a corrupt try-catch block.

Either way, one or more of the methods in the utility class is way too big and probably should be split even if there was no hard-coded length restriction.

Update: Of course in the description of the code verifier, code length is explicitly capped at 65536 bytes. But inevitably there'll be implementations out there that treat it more as a guideline. :)

Comment: Several of the methods consist of literally hundreds of case statements that all fall through to one return statement, but it has been this way for a very long time (long before I got here) and it hasn't been a problem for this long-time client. Now it's suddenly an issue. I'll check version control to see what changed in our recent release. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @smacdav Wow, commiserations.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share the following from the Java VM specification - Java SE 7 Edition (Paragraph 4.7.3, to be precise):

> The fact that end_pc is exclusive is a historical mistake in the
>   design of the Java Virtual Machine: if the Java Virtual Machine code
>   for a method is exactly 65535 bytes long and ends with an instruction
>   that is 1 byte long, then that instruction cannot be protected by an
>   exception handler. A compiler writer can work around this bug by
>   limiting the maximum size of the generated Java Virtual Machine code
>   for any method, instance initialization method, or static initializer
>   (the size of any code array) to 65534 bytes.

So this seems to be a compiler specific feature. It must be said that generating such huge code blocks should not be an issue in Java (given a sane design), but it could be an issue when automatically generated code is used.

Comment: JLS 12.2.1 states that `ClassFormatError` may only be throwed when the bytes are malformed, Thus isn't length-limitation basically a violation of this standard?

Comment: @Pacerier Possibly, depends on how you interpret the error and the situation. But this is not an error that you would run into on a daily basis I suppose, and the message text is rather readable. Good enough in my opinion.